# How to debug JavaScript on Firefox without Firebug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

How can I debug JavaScript on Firefox without Firebug? I found that not all JavaScript source files, which were being loaded initially, are shown on the left panel of the debug tool. Any chances for me to dig them out?

More background: We have to do remote debugging on a customer's machine and this machine has everything blocked except our remote connection. Also, the customer is refused to install Firebug.

Comment: If you can't install addons, I think the built-in developer tools are your best option.

Comment: Do you mean the [Script Location Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu) within Firebug's *Script* panel when talking of the 'left panel of the debug tool'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has [built-in devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), which can be opened via <kbd>F12</kbd> when Firebug is not installed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or via Firefox menu > *Developer* > *Toggle Tools*:

[image: Toggle Firefox DevTools]

Their [*Debugger* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) can be opened via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. It works similar to the one in Firebug.
Note that to be able to [debug dynamically evaluated scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Debug_eval_sources) (e.g. scripts executed via `eval()`), the scripts need to include a `//# sourceURL` comment.
*Note: If they don't include that comment, they won't be shown within the Sources side panel!*

See the following example for such a `//# sourceURL` comment (taken from the linked MDN website):

```
var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
button.addEventListener("click", evalFoo, false);

var script = "function foo() {" +
             "  console.log('called foo');" +
             "}" +
             "foo();//# sourceURL=my-foo.js";

function evalFoo() {
  eval(script);
}
```

The Firefox DevTools have a feature called ['black boxing'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Ignore_a_source) to detect JS libraries and automatically exclude them from debugging, because people normally only want to debug their sources but not third party sources. Those scripts will still be listed within the *Sources* side panel and blacklisting can be turned off for them manually.

[image: Black boxed source within Debugger panel]

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. This is the built-in dev tool I have been working with but, compare with Chrome, not all js library were prompted for debugging.

Comment: You should mention in your question that you also tried the Firefox DevTools. Note: Firebug != Firefox DevTools. I updated my answer to clarify the cases when you don't see the sources of scripts.